# Changing WooCommerce Checkout form input text CSS style

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, textfield, checkout

I was working on my wordpress site when I noticed that the input text for WooCommerce's checkout page came out as italic.

How could I go about changing the style, font, etc? The theme I am running is called VAN by ThemeStudio. They've got a Typography option in their custom menu, however whatever changes I make there aren't reflected on the checkout page.

The webpage is: http://honestabe.ca/ininkk/shopink/ (add a product to cart and go to checkout…).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey! Super sorry for being so late to reply! I was on vacation. Thank you for your answer; I'm testing it out right now so I hope it works!

Comment: It worked! I'm using the same method for future problems; thank you so much, Loic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is located in the **`woocommerce`** folder inside your "Van" active theme, within **`woocommerce.css`** file. Open this file with a code editor or directly with the wordpress editor (Appearance > Editor, then in `woocommerce` folder > `woocommerce.css` file). 
Go to line 990 and you will find this:

```css
.woocommerce form .form-row input.input-text, 
.woocommerce form .form-row textarea, 
.woocommerce-page form .form-row input.input-text, 
.woocommerce-page form .form-row text area {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
    padding: 14px 10px;
    font-family: 'Playfair Display';
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #7a7a7a;
    font-style: italic;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    outline: none;
}
```

> Change **`font-style: italic;`** by **`font-style: normal;`**

You are done…

You will certainly have to make other changes in that file. Now you know where you can do it.

Comment: @AbrahamLN It's better to set a child theme avoiding by the way losing edits and changes when the parent theme is updated...